# SSRS export tab delimited with line breaks

Tags: csv, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've created a table in SSRS 2008 with multiple rows. Meaning, 1 row of information from the database displays as multiple rows in the the table. Until I export, then it gets flattened into a single row. I'm exporting to a custom CSV that uses tab delimitation.

Is there any way I can force the export to do a line break at the end of my SSRS table rows, as opposed to the database rows? I want the end of my SSRS table rows to produce an `<CR><LF>` when exported like each field produces a `<Tab>`.

It's hard to explain. Please let me know if I can clarify anything. Thanks.

Comment: CSV is not meant to be formatted. Have you considered exporting to Excel?

Comment: Yes. Ultimately I need the file format to be an IIF so it can be imported into QuickBooks. I am trying to avoid having to go through Excel, though.